# LNK1181: cannot open input file 'boost_python.lib' in windows, boost_1_68_0

Tags: visual-studio, boost-python

I downloaded and built boost_1_68_0 (bootstrap and b2)  with VS 14 on Windows 10. I verified the build by running bjam in the lib\regex\example folder, which ran without error.

When I try to do the same thing in the lib\python\example folder I get this error for each link: LNK1181: cannot open input file 'boost_python.lib'

I verified that the boost_python.lib variants (libboost_python36-vc140-mt-gd-x32-1_68.lib, libboost_python36-vc140-mt-x32-1_68.lib, and x64 versions) are in the F:\Dev\Boost\boost_1_68_0\stage\lib path and that this path is set in LIB of msvc-setup.bat.

Normally I wouldn't worry about this and would just build from the IDE, but the boost documentation made me worry that I'd run into trouble if I didn't use bjam....

Comment: Is this the right place to ask this question? The python boost documentation appears to be a bit out of date and suggests posting on the Boost.Python mailing list, but following the links lead to 404.

Comment: You definitely don't need bjam to use Boost Python.

Comment: Thanks Dan, that's good to know. What steps, if any, do I need to perform besides building the dll. Does the python system need to be updated in some way?

Comment: IIRC, set up include and link paths for boost, and Python. In the basic case, link with the boost_python library. Sometimes you might also need to link with the Python library (don't recall the specific cases, but it will be obvious). If you're building a Python module, you will need to rename the resulting .dll to .pyd. Then just make sure it's somewhere Python searches for modules (current directory works fine).

Comment: Perfect, many thanks! I also found this link, which outlines in detail the steps you've described: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017